# Adding sum values from two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i achieve this. T2 is linked with another table which contains order details like customer name, country and classification. They have an inner join.

T1 is linked to T2 only via order code and order item.

[image]

Comment: If you provide the detail of other table which us linked to T2 then it will be helpful

Comment: please do not share your data as images, rather use text.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan the purpose here was only to give an example, If it was a sample data then for sure it would be text. Also sharing the above in text or image doesn't make any difference.

Comment: 1.The people who wants to answer any question will need to try within a DB, so will need to copy and paste sample data and your effort to that DB's medium. It would be easier to copy and paste for text data of course.                                                       2. Some people may not be able to see images because of some filterings such as firewall. [Especially read the part after `Help others reproduce the problem`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both tables report the same set of order numbers, we can try joining two subqueries each of which finds the sums in the respective tables:

```
SELECT
    t1.ORDER_NUM,
    t1.ORDER_ITEM,
    t1.PRODUCED + t2.PRODUCED AS PRODUCED
FROM
(
    SELECT ORDER_NUM, ORDER_ITEM, SUM(PRODUCED) AS PRODUCED
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY ORDER_NUM
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ORDER_NUM, ORDER_ITEM, SUM(NET_IN - NET_OUT) AS PRODUCED
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY ORDER_NUM
) t2
    ON t1.ORDER_NUM = t2.ORDER_NUM AND
       t1.ORDER_ITEM = t2.ORDER_ITEM
ORDER BY
    t1.ORDER_NUM,
    t1.ORDER_ITEM;
```

Note that the above is not necessarily an ideal approach, because a given order/item combination in one table might not appear in the other table.  A better approach would be to start the query with a reference table containing all orders and items.  That failing, we could convert the above to a full outer join.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple approach is `union all`:

```
select ordernum, orderitem, sum(produced) as produced
from ((select ordernum, orderitem, produced
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select ordernum, orderitem, netout
       from table2
      )
     ) t12
group by ordernum, orderitem;
```

This has two advantages over pre-aggregating and using `join`s:

1. It keeps all order/item pairs, even those that appear in one table.
2. If you add a `where` claus to the outer query, SQL Server is likely to "project" that into the subqueries.

Comment: But in this query net in column has not been used.

Answer (score 0):

Try for bellow query also

```
select t1.order_num,t1.order_item,sum(t1.produced)+(select sum(net_in) from t2)-(select sum(t2.net_out) from t2)PRODUCED
from t1 
group by t1.order_num,t1.order_item
```

if you have wanted the only sum from another table that time you have used select query and do the sum of a particular column.